# Cannot login to SQL server using Azure platform

Tags: sql, azure

I signed for Azure free trial and my dev team create database and it is running already but when i login to azure platform then database - connect to server it says fail to connect I reset password 2 times still same issues... can anyone help with the issue please.

I'm also looking to export full backup of my database to keep it on my local computer what is the best way to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, they were having some issues with the portal but they should be fixed now.  So if you try you should be able to log in now.

For the backup part, take a look at:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1792.sql-azure-backup-and-restore-strategy.aspx

Comment: i'm still cannot login.. i'm wondering should i use administrator user name they have on there portal beside server name or the hotmail email i used to create my account at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect from the Azure Portal or from SSMS? Have you setup your firewall rules?

Also you will use the credentials you setup for SQL Azure, not the hotmail credentials used to setup your Azure account.

Edit: Adding screen shots:

This is the form that will show when creating the server:

[image]

This is what you will see when editing from the Database portion of the Portal (remember to expand the subscription and select the server):

[image]

From either location hitting add will show:

[image]

Comment: where i can set the firewall rules?

Comment: When you create a new server you can setup the Firewall rules. To connect from the Portal (and from compute instances) you will need to select the option "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server" and you can also setup external IP addresses or address ranges to connect to the server (needed for running SSMS) After install you can select the server on the left side of the screen (managing the Database) open the subscription and select the server then there is a button that will allow you to expand and see/manage the firewall rules. Let me know if you would like screen shots.

Comment: if you can send me screen shots what's will be amazing... big thanks

Comment: Hope the screen shots help! Let me know if it looks like this will solve your issue, or we can keep trying!

Comment: Any luck with this yet? Or did you find another problem/solution?