# How to connect my webrole app (vb.net) to my sql azure database?

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-sql-database, webrole

I am creating a new application (webrole) in webforms called SGS. This application is being build using vb.net.

I am developing the app in windows 7 and have already deployed it to Windows azure.

Every time I  need to change something in the application, I change it locally and then publish it again to my production enviroment (i know about staging enviroment in azure, but I prefered the production).

The app is in the start point, now I need to connect it to my database that is in SQL Azure.

I built a new database named SGS that is on SQL Azure and I want to connect my application to it.

I would like that even when I am in the local environment, my application only connects to my sql zure database. This way I don't need any database on my local Pc.

I don't know how to accomplish this.....

The connection string (ado.net) that is on the azure is :

```
Server=tcp:mwjw08qhju.database.windows.net,1433;Database=SGS;User ID=pr@mwjw08qhju;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

My webconfig file as this information:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    Server=tcp:mwjw08qhju.database.windows.net,1433;Database=SGS;User ID=pr@mwjw08qhju;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;


    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 <!--   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
        Catalog=aspnet_1db0ca8ec36d4ba1852e5e4ec9947660;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->


    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=" <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet_1db0ca8ec36d4ba1852e5e4ec9947660;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="aspnet_1db0ca8ec36d4ba1852e5e4ec9947660Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=aspnet_1db0ca8ec36d4ba1852e5e4ec9947660;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What do I need to change to accomplish this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This set up should do exactly what you want.  It's only *slightly* more complex if you wanted to connect to SQL Server when running locally BUT SQL Azure when deployed.

To connect to SQL Azure from your local machine though, you'll need to have a firewall rule that allows traffic to reach SQL Azure.  Ironically, the [post right below yours in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536406/cannot-login-to-sql-server-using-azure-platform) has a response that should help you do this (if you haven't already).

If you set up the firewall rule and are still having issues, post back with more specifics about what's not working, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Service and Default connection strings to the connection string you received from the Azure SQL portal.

So you will get this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="mwjw08qhju.database.windows.net,1433;Database=SGS;User ID=pr@mwjw08qhju;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope that helps